# How to make dropmenu slide?

Tags: html, css

I have problem with this dropmenu. I want to slide dropmenu how on this page:https://codepen.io/dghez/pen/Kwoper, but there code is writing in scss and I don't know how to compile in css. And if help mee I will gratefull. I think that I do everthing good, but I can't make the same dropmenu how on this page.

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.nav ul{
 list-style:none;
}
.nav{
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 top:10%;
 left:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}


.nav li:hover{
 background-color:yellow;
}

.nav>ul{
 list-style:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 display:inline-block;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:green;
}
.nav>ul>li{
 position:relative;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:20px;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 float:left;
 width:136px;
 height:50px;
 line-height:50px;
 
}


.dropdown{
 position:absolute;
 top:48px;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 padding:0;
 transform:translate(0,100%);
 
 
 
 
}

.dropdown li{
 background-color:blue;
 top:48px;
 
 

 
}

.dropdown li:hover{
 background-color:orange;
}
.dropdown li{
 display:none;
}

.nav li:hover .dropdown li{
 display:block;
}

.nav li:hover .dropdown{
 transform:translate(0,0);
 transition:2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
<title>Pierwsza strona</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style100.css">

</head>
 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Graphics</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Marketing</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: With a simple google search https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is pretty simple. For this you need to convert the **SCSS into CSS**. You can use this link to do so: [SCSS to CSS converter](https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css). Also please check the output for your requirement.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #374954;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
 #main {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  background: #6bbe92;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
 #main li {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 5;
  min-width: 120px;
}
 li {
  margin: 0;
}
 .drop {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 48px;
}
 .drop div {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -100%);
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s 0.1s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s 0.1s;
  transition: all 0.5s 0.1s;
  position: relative;
}
 .drop li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3e8760 !important;
}
 #marker {
  height: 6px;
  background: #3e8760 !important;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 120px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}
 #main li:nth-child(1):hover ul div {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
 #main li:nth-child(1):hover ~ #marker {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px0);
  transform: translate(0px0);
}
 #main li:nth-child(2):hover ul div {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
 #main li:nth-child(2):hover ~ #marker {
  -webkit-transform: translate(120px0);
  -moz-transform: translate(120px0);
  -ms-transform: translate(120px0);
  transform: translate(120px0);
}
 #main li:nth-child(3):hover ul div {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
 #main li:nth-child(3):hover ~ #marker {
  -webkit-transform: translate(240px0);
  -moz-transform: translate(240px0);
  -ms-transform: translate(240px0);
  transform: translate(240px0);
}
 #main li:nth-child(4):hover ul div {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
 #main li:nth-child(4):hover ~ #marker {
  -webkit-transform: translate(360px0);
  -moz-transform: translate(360px0);
  -ms-transform: translate(360px0);
  transform: translate(360px0);
}
```

```html
<!-- not responsive yet -->
<nav>
  <ul id="main">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Portfolio
      <ul class="drop">
        <div>
        <li>Web Design</li>
        <li>Photography</li>
        <li>Graphics</li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <div id="marker"></div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps.